# Best way to store the results of a query

Tags: sql, ado.net, visual-studio-2013, c#

So I'm playing around a little with SQL and C#. I have a .cs file in which I have a method where I'm gonna use a select to get some info from my database.

I think the syntax I'm using is correct (if not please let me know). But I was wondering which is the best way to store the result. Is there a way to store the result in datasets? If not, which is the best type to store the info?

So here goes my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=XXXXXXXXXX.com;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXXXXX;User ID=XXXXXXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM HISTHDR";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return true;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What results? You're effectively storing the amount of rows returned in an integer.. not sure I see a problem here?

Comment: I think you may want to run through some tutorials because this doesn't really make enough sense to be able to give a proper response

Comment: I left the int because I was using a count. But I don't want the count, I want the actual rows of my table so that I can use to them to later store them in a csv file. @Jonesy

Comment: the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958155/fill-datatable-from-sql-server-database) shows how to fill a datatable from a query

Comment: Have you googled about it. Well known code for centuries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are executing:

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That command is (as its name implies is for NON queries) meant for UPDATES/DELETES etc...

You want to do:

```
using( DbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
{
    while ( rdr.Read() )
    {

        // ... get column data here ...//
        string s = (string) rdr["name"];
     }
 }
```